# About Database of which one suitable for develop android apps

Tags: android

I'm new to android development i want to know which databases are to develop apps and which databases suitable for app development

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of option available like:

**1.** *

> Room - Abstract Layer to SQLite

*

**2.**

> SQLite

**3.**

> Realm

**4.**

> ContentProvider